# How does the modifier .navigationTitle in SwiftUI work?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've known the .navigationTitle is the extension function of View, but how to explain the following examples?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(1..<100){ item in
                Text("Hello, \(item)!")
                    .navigationTitle("Test\(item)")
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("title in navigation")
}
```

The result show that only the modifier of first widget inside NavigationView effected.
[code results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBHRn.png)

I think the best choice is: modifier .navigationTitle is effective in NavigationView instead of the first widget inside NavigationView.

Answer (score 1):

iOS will show the first innermost `.navigationTitle`.
Your outer title will never show, as it cannot be attached to `"NavigationView`itself.

From the docs:

> A view’s navigation title is used to visually display the current navigation state of an interface. On iOS and watchOS, when a view is navigated to inside of a navigation view, that view’s title is displayed in the navigation bar. On iPadOS, the primary destination’s navigation title is reflected as the window’s title in the App Switcher. Similarly on macOS, the primary destination’s title is used as the window title in the titlebar, Windows menu and Mission Control.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter if `.navigationTitle` is inside a `NavigationView` or not. What `.navigationTitle` does is finds the `UIView` that the `View` is being displayed in, then searches for the `UIViewController` containing that `UIView` and it sets its `navigationItem.title`. That fact that only the first title param is used is probably some implementation detail, e.g. if this value is already set don't set it again, because obviously searching the UIView and UIViewController hierarchy is an expensive operation they would want to avoid.

You can verify this by implementing a `UINavigationController` in SwiftUI using `UIViewControllerRepresentable`. Then when you put a `UIHostingController` in the stack, if the SwiftUI View uses `.navigationTitle` then it still works. e.g.

```
struct NavigationControllerTestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MyNavigation {
            Text("Test Text")
                .navigationTitle("Test Title") // works despite no NavigationView
                .toolbar {
                    EditButton()
                }
        }
    }
}


struct MyNavigation<Content: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        
        
        let hc = UIHostingController(rootView: content)
        hc.rootView = content
        
        let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: hc)
        
        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UINavigationController
 
}
```

[image: Screenshot]